# MySQL query help

Tags: mysql, join, query, order-by, count

I need a query that returns the number of liked messages and orders them by the number of likes (from most to least).

I have tried:

```
SELECT users.user_id,   
       messages.author, 
       messages.message_id, 
       users.first_name, 
       messages.content, 
       COUNT(messages_id) as times_liked 
FROM liked_messages 
RIGHT JOIN messages ON messages.message_id = liked_messages.messages_id 
JOIN users ON messages.author = users.user_id 
GROUP BY messages_id 
ORDER BY times_liked desc
```

However it only returns one record not all of them. I could really use some help!

[image]

Comment: First of all, format your code properly.  Looking at your unformatted code, most people will just skip it.

Comment: Also learning to use a proper `GROUP BY` will likely solve your problem.  Pretty much all of the other dbms will not even run your code.  Even newer version of MySQL will not run your code.

Comment: You must group by MESSAGE and count LIKES. Whereas you group by likes.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

There are times when a subquery is better:

```
SELECT  users.user_id,   
        m.author, 
        m.message_id, 
        users.first_name, 
        m.content, 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM liked_messages
             WHERE message_id = m.message_id ) AS times_liked 
    FROM messages AS m
    JOIN users ON m.author = users.user_id 
    ORDER BY times_liked desc;
```